# Inner join with count in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get the query for details along with the status if the particular column exists for that report using the below query.

```
select rh.Rec_ID 
   ,rh.Report_ID 
   ,rh.Report_Name 
   ,rh.Source_Type_Display 
   ,rh.Description 
   ,rh.IndID 
   ,rh.Name 
   ,rh.Time_Updated 
   ,count(*) OVER() as TotalCount
   ,case when count(rd.demo) > 0 THEN 'Completed' ELSE 'incomplete' END
  FROM v_Report_Header_OV rh 
  inner join v_Table_NI_Report_Demo rd
  ON rh.Report_ID = rd.Report_ID
  WHERE rh.Client_ID = 12324
```

I am getting  below error

`Column 'v_Report_Header_OV.Rec_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

I am not sure why i am getting error, Could any one please help on this

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed `group by`

```
select rh.Rec_ID 
   ,rh.Report_ID 
   ,rh.Report_Name 
   ,rh.Source_Type_Display 
   ,rh.Description 
   ,rh.IndID 
   ,rh.Name 
   ,rh.Time_Updated 
   ,count(*) OVER() as TotalCount
   ,case when count(rd.demo) > 0 THEN 'Completed' ELSE 'incomplete' END
  FROM v_Report_Header_OV rh 
  inner join v_Table_NI_Report_Demo rd
  ON rh.Report_ID = rd.Report_ID
  WHERE rh.Client_ID = 12324
 group by rh.Rec_ID 
   ,rh.Report_ID 
   ,rh.Report_Name 
   ,rh.Source_Type_Display 
   ,rh.Description 
   ,rh.IndID 
   ,rh.Name 
   ,rh.Time_Updated
```